# Enabling Local Cache on Sitecore Azure App Services

Tags: azure, paas

I've read the following article https://blog.baslijten.com/increase-your-sitecore-performance-by-enabling-the-local-cache-on-azure-app-services/ that says how to enable Local Cache option in the Azure App Services, however, during my research, I found more things to consider as follows

> - If your web application write logs into the web contents (for example
>     'App_Data' folder) then these log files will be discarded when the web
>     application is restarted or application is moved to a different
>     virtual machine
> - Newly deployed code changes will not be reflected until you restart
>     the site

That said, I wonder if there are any Sitecore recommendations or limitations in enable the Local Cache option on Azure App Services.

Thoughts?

Comment: We do a lot of Sitecore on Azure App Services and have found the Local Cache options to not significantly improve the performance of the system in our testing.  Further, as you mentioned, there are a number of drawbacks as well.  Unless you are tuning to 99% you can probably find lower hanging fruit to make your site go faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had opened a ticket with Sitecore Support and they said the following

> **Azure Local Cache is not supported by Sitecore as it was never tested**.
>
> It might work at first glance, however we are not aware of any
>   drawback so we suggest you not to use it.

In addition to that, **Sitecore Support have requested that future versions of Sitecore could be compatible with Local Cache**

> **The reference number of the request is 398580**.
>
> More information about public reference numbers can be found here:
>   https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this conversation that Local Cache is recommended by this Knowledge Base [article](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0909298), as a way to speed start up time when Azure performs updates:

> The Local Cache feature is a Microsoft Azure App Service feature, not a Sitecore one. However, some Sitecore Managed Cloud implementations use Local Cache to improve the speed of Sitecore restarting. In cases where the Microsoft Azure platform performs an update that triggers a transient interruption to the Azure App Service, Local Cache can reduce the duration of any related downtime. The feature makes the files for implementation available on the local Azure App Service host, so instead of copying the implementation files from the central location after the service restart down to the host powering the App Service (which can take time), the files in Local Cache are immediately available.